# How do I pass request.identity to the view

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

def edit(id: String) = SecuredAction(WithService("master")).async {implicit request =>

```
    val futureEmp = collection.flatMap(_.find(Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> id))).cursor[Employee]().collect[List]())

futureEmp.map { emps: List[Employee] =>
  implicit val message = messagesApi.preferred(request)

  Ok(html.editForm(id, employeeForm.fill(emps.head)))
}.recover {
  case t: TimeoutException =>
    Logger.error("Problem found in employee edit process")
    InternalServerError(t.getMessage)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Once you have wired up Silhouette in a play module, and injected your user model into the Environment trait:

```
trait YourCustomEnv extends Env {
  type I = User // <- Whatever user model your app uses
  type A = JWTAuthenticator
}
```

... you will be able to access the identity on a Secured endpoint by accessing the identity member:

```
def index() = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    // The model of the authenticated user available here
    val user: User = request.identity
    Future.successful(Ok)
}
```

Assuming that you are using Twirl as the templating engine, you can pass this object to the view by adding it as a parameter to the template:

```
@(user: models.User)
```

... and calling the template like so from your controller:

```
def index() = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    val user: User = request.identity
    Future.successful(Ok(views.html.home(user))))
}
```

Comment: Thank you Liam Maloney, Let me do it and see.

Comment: I am using twirl.